# Cannot seem to redirect Tomcat logs to log4j

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I am using this doc to change my Tomcat loggers to log4j:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

my log4j.properties file is as shown in the document, except I changed this line to confirm it's working:
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/test_catalina

I still see a file logs/catalina.out and not logs/test_catalina, which makes me think either log4j is not being used or my properties file is not read.

I have tomcat-juli-adapters.jar, log4j-1.2.17.jar and log4j.properties in lib
and overwrote bin/tomcat-juli.jar

running set -x catalina.sh start shows:

```
 eval "/a/java64/jdk1.8.0/bin/java" "-Dnop" -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dlog4j.debug=true  -Djava.endorsed.
dirs="/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/endorsed" -classpath "/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" -Dcatalina.base="/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62" -Dcatalina.home="/opt/apache-tom
cat-7.0.62" -Djava.io.tmpdir="/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/temp" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start &
```

I also have no logging.properties file on disk:

```
ls conf/*.properties 
conf/catalina.properties
```

I would really appreciate advice on how to debug this -- I'm not sure if a jar is not being found properly, if my log4j.properties has a problem, or Tomcat just plain can't tell I'd like log4j.

Using Tomcat version  Server number:  7.0.62.0

Answer (score 1):

> I would really appreciate advice on how to debug this

The switch of sending Tomcat log messages from java.util.logging to log4j 1.x is performed by Apache Commons Logging library. (Its compiled package-renamed version is in those `tomcat-juli.jar` and `tomcat-juli-adapters.jar`)

There is a debug setting [available](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/troubleshooting.html#Log_Discovery_Diagnostics) in Apache Commons Logging. After package renaming the setting name becomes `org.apache.juli.logging.diagnostics.dest`.

I do not see any evident error in those steps that you performed. Dummy issues may be: are the files readable?

Notes:

1. It is possible to put `tomcat-juli-adapters.jar` into $CATALINA_HOME/bin instead of /lib, but you need to update CLASSPATH variable (in your `bin/setenv.sh`) so that it is included in the value of `-classpath` argument to java. Repacking the two jars into a single jar file is also an option.
2. As mentioned by [tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j), deleting `conf/logging.properties` makes java.util.logging to fallback to default configuration. You may wish to explicitly configure that file.
3. Source code for `tomcat-juli.jar` and `tomcat-juli-adapters.jar` can be found at Maven Central. Those libraries have  [groupId=org.apache.tomcat.extras](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.tomcat.extras%22)